# Inflation-restriction exact sequence in nonabelian group cohomology

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a group with normal subgroup $H$ and let $M$ be an abelian group on which $G$ acts. The associated inflation-restriction exact sequence is
$$1 \to H^1(G/H, M^H) \to H^1(G, M) \to H^1(H, M)^{G/H} \to H^2(G/H, M^H).$$
This can in fact be extended to an explicit seven-term exact sequence; see [this paper.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869312003390)

Now let us drop the assumption that $M$ is abelian. One can still define cohomology functors $H^i$. For $H^0$, $H^1$, and $H^2$ this is done for example in Giraud's "Cohomologie non abélienne".

To what extent does there exist an inflation-restriction exact sequence in the non-abelian setting?